# OnBackPressedCallback not trigger after screen rotation

Tags: android

i have follow (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher)

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull final Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    final OnBackPressedCallback _fragmentOnBackPressedCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true)
    {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed()
        {
            sendData();
        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, _fragmentOnBackPressedCallback);
}
```

in my activity in onCreate i do

```
final OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true)
        {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed()
            {
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                else
                    navigateUpInMenu();
            }
        };
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
}
```

It work great, but when i rotate the phone the sendData method is not called. Do i miss something ?
I'm using androidx.activity:activity:1.1.0

Comment: Do you have any other `OnBackPressedCallback` instances that you've registered? For example, any registered using the Activity's Lifecycle?

Comment: Some other fragment execute the same code. And the mainActivity

Comment: Can you include that code from your `MainActivity` that is also using an `OnBackPressedCallback`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have `OnBackPressedCallback` registered as long as `View` or `viewLifecycleOwner` of Fragment is alive.

`viewLifeCycleOwner` lives between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView` so you don't need to unregister callback either to prevent any potential memory leak due to lifecycle of Fragment.

I use

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)

}

    val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(false) {

        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
             sendData()
       }
   }
```

With a callBack property you can also enable or disable based on some conditions or lifecycle events.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    callback.isEnabled = true
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    callback.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and got it resolved with help from some hints above. The problem for me was that I was registering `onBackPressedDispatcher` both from my Fragments and from my MainActivity.

Before the recent updates to Android, I was using `onBackPressed()` in my MainActivity to hide a drawer before exiting the app, and `onBackPressedDispatcher` in my Fragments to ask the user for confirmation before navigating back. This approach worked fine. Now, `onBackPressed()` in Activities is deprecated and `onBackPressedDispatcher` is recommended to be used instead. This also worked fine, until you rotate the display and suddenly the Fragment back press gets ignored and the MainActivity back press code gets executed instead. I don't know if it's a bug or not, but I will avoid using it.

I've fixed the issue by moving the `onBackPressedDispatcher` code from my MainActivity into the first "Main" Fragment. This way, back presses are only controlled by Fragments, which in my case means that only one element at a time is responsible for controlling the back press behavior.

Answer (score 0):

According to official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#lifecycle)

> onAttach(Activity) called once the fragment is associated with its
> activity.

A good thing to do is to move the `onBackPressedDispatcher` in the `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and found out that adding the the callback in a non-lifecycle-aware manner fixes the issue for me:

```
// MainActivity#onCreate()
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(callback)
```

You also need to take care of the callback-removal now, but currently I'm not sure whether `onDestroy()` is the right place to do it:

```
// MainActivity#onDestroy()
callback.remove()
```